# Cancel Blender operators from python

Tags: python, scripting, operator

Is it possible to cancel a recently run operator from a handler, if it fails to pass some condition?

I basicaly want to restrict some objects which have a custom property from editing, so I want to create a handler that would immediately cancel and abort unnecessary operatios. In short, I want to prevent any changes being done to object's mesh.

I tried checking bpy.context.active_operator in a load_scene_post handler for a specific bl_idname, and run bpy.ops.ed.undo() if it matched the "operator blacklist". However, it makes Blender crash, I think because it tries to cancel an operator when running modal. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve